# React custom hook without boilerplate for closure

Tags: react-hooks, closures, boilerplate

I have a component that should listen to some socket events. I register them as follows to avoid spurious register/unregister actions of the event listeners (`socketListen` returns the destruction of the listener itself, so that is taken care of).

```
useEffect(() => socketListen('name', newName => setName(newName)), []);
```

Now as I have more of these kind of listeners, I want to get rid of boilerplate code by writing a custom hook

```
const useListener = (event, callback) => {
  useEffect(() => socketListen(event, callback), [event, callback]);
};
```

to be then used as

```
useListener('name', newName => setName(newName));
```

intending to put focus on the actual action performed and not on the useEffect invokation.
Now the issue is that I hand over a closure (invoking the state setter `setName`) to my custom hook which implies that the `callback` in `useListener` is changed on rerender and therefore again generates spurious listener registering/unregistering. To salvage I could wrap the closure in a `useCallback` but that would defy my original goal of reducing the code clutter.

I think I can see the functional reason for above problem (and hope to have conveyed that in my writing), but I wonder if there is a convenient way to write a helper function to do what I intended to accomplish with `useListener` without additional boilerplate code. My actual code uses more complex closures, but I hope that this example suffices to pinpoint my issue.

Comment: `useListener('name', setName)`. `setName` returned by a `useState()` or `useReducer()` is already memoized, and `setName` in this case would be equivalent to `newName => setName(newName)`

Comment: My example is lackluster in that respect. I should have written `newName => setName(prefix + newName)` where `prefix is some prop or state`, i.e. the closure alters in functionality even by distinct side effects. Your answer below does help a lot though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to bail out of the requirement for a memoized closure by using a reference:

```js
const useListener = (event, callback) => {
  const ref = useRef();
  ref.current = callback;
  useEffect(() => (
    socketListen(event, newName => ref.current(newName))
  ), [event]);
};
```

It's important that you write `newName => ref.current(newName)` instead of just `ref.current` so that the property access `ref.current` doesn't occur until the `socketListen` callback is invoked. That way `ref.current` is equal to the most recent `callback` passed to `useListener()` and isn't referencing the stale closure from the first call to `useListener()`.

Comment: Perfect, so far this seems to meet all my requirements. At least the boilerplate (some of which is to be expected by what I intend to to) is entirely in the externalized function. This also helped my understanding of hooks further (`useRef` in this instance) since from this example it is clearly visible that `useListener` is still called on every re-render, but hides the otherwise necessary update of the `useEffect` within the reference update. In particular `const ref = useRef(); ref.current = callback;` cannot be replaced by `const ref = useRef(callback)` as this would skip the update.